# Different viewport widths for landscape and portrait

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, viewport

My website is more or less optimized for mobile devices, however it needs a minimum width of 480 px.
Using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480">
```

works well, but only in portrait mode. If I switch to landscape, it uses 480 px too, which makes everything too big.
Is there a way with maybe a script to switch to a higher width if landscape (mobile users only) is used?
Thank you.

Comment: I just realized that this solution would mean hat even very big mobile devices would use only the next bigger resolution, which would also be bad. However setting the viewport to device-width if the device width is over 480px would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.orientation or jQuery Mobile Orientation Event

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_orientation.asp

```
<script>
  function doOnOrientationChange()
  {
    switch(window.orientation) 
    {  
      case -90:
      case 90:
        alert('landscape');
        break; 
      default:
        alert('portrait');
        break; 
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);

  // Initial execution if needed
  doOnOrientationChange();
</script>
```

or JQuery

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(event){
  alert("Orientation is: " + event.orientation);
});
```

You can then change the vieport

```
document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content","width=640");
```

Comment: Still trying to get javascript:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=480">
<script>
  function doOnOrientationChange()
  {
    switch(window.orientation) 
    {  
      case -90:
      case 90:
        alert('landscape');
        break; 
      default:
        alert('portrait');
        break; 
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', oOnOrientationChange);
  document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content","width=640");
  // Initial execution if needed
  doOnOrientationChange();
</script>`
I see the messages, but it wont change to a higher width.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="width=480" />
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            if(window.innerWidth >= 480) {
                var mvp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
                mvp.setAttribute('content','width=device-width', 'initial-scale=1');
            }
        }
     </script>
```

I used this as a solution, after I realized I was forgetting bigger resolutions on tablets etc, which would only would have made me having to make a dozen of those steps. Its derived from [Why is CSS min-width causing my responsive site to be zoomed in on a mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669937/why-is-css-min-width-causing-my-responsive-site-to-be-zoomed-in-on-a-mobile). Works like a charm.

Comment: Nevermind, for some reason it sometimes loads the script too late (or skips it) and then it will jump back to the default layout. At least on my Android device with Chrome. I am out of ideas. Maybe a media query? But I have no idea about them at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use @media queries in CSS, along with the @viewport CSS tag, instead of the meta viewport tag. There's a good explanation of how to do this here:

http://www.html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/

An example from the above link:

```
@media (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  @viewport {
    width: 640px;
  }
}
```

You could use this to set different viewports for portrait and landscape, and more generically narrower and wider screens.

Comment: note this feature doesn't have great support among browsers as of 2018. Seems mostly just Edge: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-deviceadaptation